# INSERT Query with Parameters in VS2010

Tags: vb.net, apostrophe, sqlparameter

I do not understand why it's not inserting to my database whenever I include an apostrophe in my `txtParticulars.Text` and `txtPayTo.Text`.

The error is this:`Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''Joy's Boutique','Top's,'Issued')'.`

My textbox values are:

`txtPayTo.Text` > Joy's Boutique
`txtParticulars` > Top's
`cmbRemarks.SelectedItem` > Issued

But whenever my `txtParticulars` and `txtPayTo` values does not have an apostrophe, my data saves.

The following is my code:

```
sql1 = "INSERT INTO Table1(Check_No,Voucher_No,Issue_Date,Company_Name,Bank_Type,Amount_in_Figure,Amount_in_Words,Payee,Particulars,Remarks) VALUES(@CheckNo,@VoucherNo,@Date,@CompName,@BankType,@AmtInFigure,@AmtInWords,@PayTo,@Particulars,@Remarks)"

                    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql1, myConnection)

                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckNo", txtCheckNo.Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VoucherNo", txtVoucherNo.Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dtpDate.Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompName", txtCompName.Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankType", txtBankType.Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmtInFigure", txtAmtInFigure.Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmtInWords", txtAmtInWords.Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayTo", txtPayTo.Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Particulars", txtParticulars.Text)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", cmbRemarks.SelectedItem)

                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us *which* TextBox, and if you get an error message then include the text of that too.

Comment: edited it sir @AndrewMorton

Comment: Use `Add` instead of `AddWithValue`. Like `cmd1.Parameters.Add("@PayTo", SqlDbType.Varchar)        cmd1.Parameters("@PayTo").Value = txtPayTo.Text`

Comment: you can `Add` in one line: `cmd1.Parameters.Add("@PayTo", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txtPayTo.Text`

Comment: OMG it worked!!! Thank you so much mister!! :D I wish I could vote tho. But thanks a lot! :) @AlexB.

Comment: I wrote an answer so if you'd like to vote ;)

Comment: I'm afraid my reputation is not enough :( @AlexB.

Comment: No problem. But you could accept my answer by clicking on the arrow on the left

Comment: I did but it fades and says that they require 15 reputation so i can vote for an answer :) @AlexB.

Comment: [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You don't need any rep to accept.

Comment: oh sorry. I thought you meant the arrow. Sorry mister, I just accepted it. Thanks so much! :) @AlexB.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant the mark. You're welcome  glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `AddWithValue`.
The latter has to guess the correct database type by the value passed in.
The `Add` method is more reliant on that (as long as you don´t use the `Add(string, object)` overload).

Based on your example:

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@PayTo", SqlDbType.Varchar)
cmd1.Parameters("@PayTo").Value = txtPayTo.Text
```

or as one line (thanks to Plutonix):

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@PayTo", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txtPayTo.Text
```